# Ping fails to find host but NSLookup resolves okay on Windows

Tags: networking, windows-8, dns, ping, nslookup

We have an intermittent problem on Windows 8 whereby Ping fails to find the host but NSLookup resolves it correctly.

- Ping host1 - fails with ping could not find host
- Ping host1.domain.local - also fails with ping could not find host
- IPConfig /displayDNS - lists host1 as Name does not exist
- NSLookup host1 - works fine and resolves router correctly.

Have now done a network trace on this and seemingly found the following:

1. The first ping request for host1 does not look to DNS for resolution
   but NbtNs, this fails and writes that failure to DNS cache.
2. Second ping request for host1.domain.local does actually look to DNS 
   for resolution but looks to secondary DNS server rather than Primary 
   DNS server!  This fails because secondary DNS server is on the
   external network, external to the domain.
3. Any subsequent ping requests to either host1 or host1.domain.local
   fail because they are answered by the DNS cache with the previous
   failures.

Does any of this make sense, moreover what can I do to correct this weird behaviour and get Win 8 networking stack functioning properly?

I have read about this intermittent problem in various other threads but still no one seems to have a long term solution.

Comment: What happens if you try to ping in the other direction? If it works one way but not the other, the remote host might be configured to drop pings.

Comment: Ping by IP number works fine, always.  Just name resolution that goes wrong sometimes.

Comment: Further info: Ping DNS server - ok but returns IPv6 address, not IPv4 <- could this be the cause of the problem

Comment: I'm not really familiar with IPv6, so maybe? Check if IPv6 is enabled on both computer's? Can you ping both ways by IPv6 address?

Comment: Ping Workstation -4 (from server) - ok, Ping Workstation -6 (from server) - fails, Ping Server -4 (from workstation) - ok, Ping Server -6 (from workstation) - fails

Comment: Which address does nslookup provide? v4 or v6?

Comment: NSlookup returns IPv4 addresses

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8084/discussion-between-jikag-and-nickc)

Answer (score 2):

Think I got it. Was having the same problem. Turned off IPV6 (disabled protocol in network adapter properties, i.e. unchecked box), and now it works.

By the way, I had to turn off IPV6 on the DNS server too.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off DNSCache service seems to solve the problem.  This suggests to me serious bugs in Win 8 DNSCache service.  Unless there is some other explanation for what is causing the DNS Cache to get corrupted in the first place.

Comment: Just curious, did you try flushing and resetting the client resolver cache using `ipconfig /flushdns` before you turned off DNSCache service?

Comment: Yes IPConfig /flushDNS usually cleared the problem.  I say usually because just occasionally even that didn't work either.