# ping can't resolve hostname, but nslookup can, in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, ping

So, does `ping` really don't use DNS?

Here is my case:

```
$ nslookup maroon
Server:         192.168.2.102
Address:        192.168.2.102#53

maroon  canonical name = coral.
Name:   coral
Address: 192.168.2.102

$ dig maroon
;; ANSWER SECTION:
maroon.                 0       IN      CNAME   coral.
coral.                  0       IN      A       192.168.2.102
```

All look good. Now:

```
$ ping maroon
ping: maroon: Name or service not known
```

But pinging the IP works. So as suggested in [avahi: ping can't resolve hostname, but nslookup can](https://superuser.com/questions/704785/avahi-ping-cant-resolve-hostname-but-nslookup-can), I did a `strace ping`, and its output is enclosed at the bottom, from Ubuntu 17.04 zesty.

Following "[Ping fails to find host but NSLookup resolves okay](https://superuser.com/questions/571392/)", I turned off IPV6 as well:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
```

But the problem remains the same.
Please help.

PS. The `strace ping` output:

```
7062  open("/sys/fs/kdbus/0-system/bus", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (N
o such file or directory)
7062  socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 5
7062  getsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
7062  setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
7062  setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, [8388608], 4) = 0
7062  getsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
7062  setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
7062  setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [8388608], 4) = 0
7062  connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 33) = 0
7062  getsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PEERCRED, {pid=1, uid=0, gid=0}, [12]) = 0
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 201194451}) = 0
7062  fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
7062  getsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN, [0], [4]) = 0
7062  getsockname(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, NULL}, [2]) = 0
7062  geteuid()                         = 0
7062  sendmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(3)=[{"\0AUTH EXTERNAL ", 15}, {"30", 2}, {"\r\nNEGOTIATE_UNIX_FD\r\nBEGIN\r\n", 28}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 45
7062  gettid()                          = 7062
7062  getrandom("B\t\26\262\335\6\f\33\337\321C\250\374\2779|", 16, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 16
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 201935158}) = 0
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 202039305}) = 0
7062  recvmsg(5, 0x7ffdff00f5e0, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 202205684}) = 0
7062  ppoll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, {24, 998989000}, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}], left {24, 998979401})
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 202392820}) = 0
7062  recvmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"OK 46f9158405c271efea96759d59263"..., 256}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 52
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 202572558}) = 0
7062  sendmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0m\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 128}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 128
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 202751135}) = 0
7062  recvmsg(5, 0x7ffdff00f540, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 202897197}) = 0
7062  ppoll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, {24, 999038000}, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}], left {24, 997085204})
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 205068245}) = 0
7062  recvmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\2\1\1\r\0\0\0\1\0\0\0E\0\0\0\6\1s\0\10\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
7062  recvmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{":1.59975\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\1u\0\1\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1s\0\0"..., 77}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 77
7062  sendmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"l\1\2\1 \0\0\0\2\0\0\0\242\0\0\0\1\1o\0\31\0\0\0/org/fre"..., 184}, {"\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0maroon\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 216
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 205502630}) = 0
7062  recvmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\4\1\1\r\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\225\0\0\0\1\1o\0\25\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
7062  recvmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"/org/freedesktop/DBus\0\0\0\2\1s\0\24\0\0\0"..., 157}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 157
7062  recvmsg(5, 0x7ffdff00f670, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
7062  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {416062, 205942095}) = 0
7062  ppoll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, {44, 999560000}, NULL, 8) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}], left {44, 131613738})
7062  recvmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"l\3\1\1<\0\0\0.\241\3\0f\0\0\0\5\1u\0\2\0\0\0", 24}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 24
7062  recvmsg(5, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\6\1s\0\10\0\0\0:1.59975\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\1s\0\"\0\0\0"..., 156}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 156
7062  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
7062  close(5)                          = 0
7062  open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
```

I.e., in my Ubuntu 17.04 zesty, the `ping` seems to be consulting `/sys/fs/kdbus/0-system/bus`, which results in

> Resource temporarily unavailable

This seems to be a Ubuntu 17.04 specific problem, as I have the same setup in Ubuntu 16.04 before, and there were not problems then.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing /etc/nsswitch.conf as shown here:

http://stuartfeeser.com/2013/02/11/ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you @ParoXoN, I'm out of town now and will get back to you when I'm back home. Thanks again.

Comment: This helped me in archlinux yesterday.

Comment: This is a good example for why an answer should not just be a link, seeing as that domain is now offline. From the Internet archive, the short answer was: edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and replace the `hosts:` value with this: `files dns`.  Note that this may not be an ideal solution, since it means you'll be hitting DNS for any .local names which don't get resolved via your hosts file, but it did work.